# React-navigation, conditionally set setOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to set Headerleft:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation?.setOptions({
      cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forModalPresentationIOS,
    });

    if (headerCancel) {
      navigation?.setOptions({
        headerLeft: (props: { onPress: () => void; analyticsTag: string }) => (
          <HeaderCancel {...props} />
        ),
      });
    }
  }, [navigation, headerCancel]);
```

I am navigating to the screen using:

```
navigate(AppRoutes.WebViewScreen.Name, {
        uri: url,
        headerCancel: true,
      });
```

Stack:

```
<RootStack.Screen
    name={AppRoutes.WebViewScreen.Name}
    component={WebViewScreen as UnsafeNavigationScreen}
    options={{
      presentation: 'modal',
      title: '',
      headerShown: true,
      headerBackTitleVisible: false,
      animationEnabled: true,
      headerLeft: (props) => <GenericHeaderBack {...props} />,
    }}
  />
```